# ajax jQuery 3.1 Send Data via POST to C#

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, post

i'am trying to send some data using ajax call method to C# Web API , it works fine with 'GET Method' so far here's my Code But i get `404 Not found` error when i try to pass parameters with 'POST':
Javascript

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",       //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb          
     url: "/api/account/updateuser/",       // Location of the service
     data: { Email: user, Roles: Roles },
     success: function (result) {//On Successful service call
         console.log(result);
     }
});
```

C# Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
public string UpdateUser(string Email,string Roles)
{
    return Email;
}
```

i have also tested This Web API using PostMan Google Chrome extension and it works fine too , Thanks .

** EDIT : When i Just send a request without parameter it work fine .

```
[HttpPost]
public string UpdateUser()
{
    return "HI";
}
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",       //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb          
                url: "/api/account/updateuser/",       // Location of the service
                data: {},
                success: function (result) {//On Successful service call
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Check the network tab in your browser developer tools, and see whether the call is completing successfully or not, and if not what the error is.

Comment: What is the problem here ?

Comment: Have you specified your route url in apicontroller..

Comment: Hi , i Have Updated my Question , the problem is i can't send any data with Post request , and yes i have specified the Rout URL in Controller , already Used POSTMAN to Test my Web API ( with POST method) and it works Fine , but when i proceed a call via ajax it says `404 Not Found`

Comment: You can use data: JSON.stringify({ Email: user, Roles: Roles }), in place of data: {Email: user, Roles: Roles}. Hope it helps

Comment: @JustinHarvey i have check the Network Tab it Shows updateuser/ ---- 404 Not found it seems like ajax isn't sending the Data i guess .

Comment: So this means it is not finding you web api resource at the location specified.  So you need to check the URL you are seeing it using in the browser against the URL where the resource is.

Comment: @JustinHarvey i told you earlier that when i use GET Request it works Fine and also i have tried to send a POST Request With POSTMAN ( a chrome extension to test web API) and it works Fine .
** Edit : i have changed my URL to /api/account/updateuser/?Email=EMai&Roles=Roles and it works .

Answer (score 0):

Change your ajax request by adding `dataType` and `contentType` to have a valid json serialization on your server side

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: requestUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (result) {}
      );
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply , but nothing changed .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like json serialize issue. Please check it like below

```
var request = JSON.stringify({
         Email: user, 
         Roles: Roles
    });

$.ajax({
     type: "POST",       //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb          
     url: "/api/account/updateuser/",       // Location of the service
     contentType: "application/json",
     dataType: "json",
     data: request,
     success: function (result) {//On Successful service call
         console.log(result);
     }
});
```

And in c# side

```
[HttpPost]
public string UpdateUser(string Email,string Roles)
{
    return Email;
}
```

Comment: But it seems like Data doesn't Match you parse two Strings in JSON then trying to Read two Class in C#

Comment: Are user and Roles are string values or objects in js?

Comment: They are String

Answer (score 0):

Try using ActionResult return type in your controller function and return a content result object. Also make sure you stringify the json before posting it to controller -

Client script:

```
var userData = { Email: 'prashanth@gmail.com', Roles: 'Software Developer' };
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",       //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb          
                url: "/api/account/updateuser/",       // Location of the service
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: JSON.stringify(userData),
                success: function (result) {//On Successful service call
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
```

C# Controller code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult updateUser(string Email, string Roles)
{
    return Content(Email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an object as parameter.

You could even use an dynamic object parameter, so you don't have to write a class for.

---

**Dynamic**

Your request stays the same, but you should add the datatypes:

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",       //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb          
 url: "/api/account/updateuser/",       // Location of the service
 data: { Email: user, Roles: Roles },
 contentType: "application/json",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (result) {//On Successful service call
     console.log(result);
 }
});
```

And your C# controller like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public string UpdateUser(dynamic User)
{
    var roles = User.Roles;
    var mail = User.Email;
    return mail;
}
```

---

**User Class**

Or you create a class for the User.

```
class User 
{ string Email; string Roles; }
```

And pass an User object:

```
[HttpPost]
public string UpdateUser(User User)
{
    var roles = User.Roles;
    var mail = User.Email;
    return mail;
}
```